# regex lookarounds: how to extract a full match with optional lookahead

Tags: regex, qt

to describe the problem:

I have some text with mail-header-lines like

```
From: me
To: you
Subject: welcome, this is a long line of subject with two 
         lines of text
Attachements: welcome.jpg, foo.pdf
```

the last line ('Attachements: welcome.jpg, foo.pdf') is OPTIONAL.
so maybe this text only looks like

```
From: me
To: you
Subject: welcome, this is a short line of subject
```

I need to extract the Subject-Line(s), without the text 'Subject:'. leading and trailing whitespace are no problem.

the only operation I can use is a SINGLE QT-Regex-call that returns a FULL MATCH *ONLY*.

great, isn't it ?

I tried with success

```
(?<=Subject:)(?:\s*)(.*)(?=Attachements:)
```

but how do I make the 'Attachements:'-line optional ?

When there is no Attachement:-line, I expect the text/string to end with the Subject:-line(s).

any idea ?

Comment: Are you using `QRegExp` or `QRegularExpression`?

Comment: to be honest: I don't know. I'm using a product that is created with Qt (5.7.1). And they allow for just a single line of REGEX in their interface. :-(

Comment: Let's assume this is `QRegularExpression`. Try [`(?s)Subject:\s*\K.*?(?=\RAttachements:|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/NbRBF9/3).

Comment: Else, try [`(?<=Subject:)\s*((?:(?![\r\n]Attachements:).)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/HXMdQ4/1)

Comment: it works! great. I will try to understand how and why ;-)

Comment: The last one? Or both? I will post with explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=Subject:)\s*((?:(?![\r\n]Attachements:).)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HXMdQ4/1)

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=Subject:)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a position inside a string where there is a `Subject:` substring immediately to the left of the current location
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `((?:(?![\r\n]Attachements:).)*)` - Capturing group 1 that matches any char (`QRegExp` regex `.` pattern even matches line breaks), zero or more repetitions as many as possible (`*`), that does not start a CR/LF + `Attachments:` char sequence. This construct is called a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookeahead `(?!...)` for`Attachments`

```
(?<=^Subject: )(?:(?!^Attachements:)[\s\S])+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qoHE2v/5/)

Btw. I've changed `.*` to `[\S\s]*` to allow newlines in the subject.

Comment: thank you. I also tried the variants with \z. but: your sample does not contain the 'Attachement:'-line. and it does not cut out only the Subject:.

Comment: In fact, `([\S\s](?!Attachements:))+` is not a correct tempered greedy token, you should temper the dot before it matches a char, use `(?:(?!Attachements:)[\s\S])+`

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew, could you tell why is that? - my regexp seem to work correctly (but I'm eaget to learn)